# Disqus refuses to embed images for some users. Error says: "You must be logged in to upload an image." Why?

Tags: disqus

Not sure how to get this solved. The error message generated doesn't relate to the situation. The user (me) is logged in and can make a post, just not load an image to the post. I've tried very small images 10 kb just to see if that's an issue, no difference. Been happening for months now on Discus sites. (can't find the Disqus dev forums either)

Anybody versed in this issue?

Answer (score 1):

---

---

### TL;DR:

> **Your browser is blocking third-party cookies**.
>
> **To get this working**, you should **allow third party cookies**.
>
> **In your browser:**
>
> Privacy settings > Cookies > [ Allow third-party cookies / Don't block third-party cookies ]
>
> or add Disqus to your Whitelist as "Site that can always use cookies".

---

---

### 1. Identification of the problem:

> **When you get this message:** *You must be logged in to upload an image*
>
> on **Google Chrome** during the **Image upload** on **Disqus** while beeing logged in,
>
> [image: disqus error message: You must be logged in to upload an image]
>
> **then you should look, if your browsers address bar has is this icon:**
>
> [image: google chrome third party cookie blocked icon/indicator]
>
> **This means, that *your browser is blocking third-party cookies*,**
>
> **this feature was introduced in Chrome 84.** (see section 3. Education)

---

---

### 2. Solving the problem:

> **1.** Paste this in your address bar `chrome://settings` or 3 via
> dots
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings main page]

> **2.** Privacy and security
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings privacy and security page]

> **3.** Cookies and other site data
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings Cookies and other site data page]
>
> **To get Disqus uploads working again:**
>
> **Option-A: Add Disqus** to your **Whitelist** of sites that can use always cookies.
>
> To do so, press the **Add** Button.
>
> This option is less tragic/evil than Option-B, because only Disqus may track your activity on sites using Disqus platform, while Option-B would allow any third-party coockies of any site in non-Incognito Mode.
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings privacy and security page - Cookie Whitelist]
>
> Insert/Copy&Paste this `[*.]disqus.com` and press **Add**, and thats all.
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings privacy and security page - Cookie Whitelist ADD]
>
> **or choose Option-B:** *Block third-party cookies "only" in Incognito*
>
> Be warned! This setting will in non-Incognito Mode heavily have impact on your privacy!
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings privacy and security page - Chevrons]
>
> **For more details, press on the right side the Chevrons:**
>
> [image: Google Chrome settings cookies and other site data page]
>
> **Voila!**

---

---

### 3. Education about the problem:

> **Some more informations, how this affects the web:**
>
> https://publift.com/third-party-cookies/
>
> https://www.searchenginejournal.com/chrome-84-3rd-party-cookies/374529/
>
> https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/

### What are third party cookies?

> Third party cookies are used for ad retargeting and [behavioral
> advertising](https://publift.com/contextual-advertising/#Contextual_vs_Behavioral_Advertising). By adding tags to a page, advertisers can track a user
> across the web as they visit different websites. This allows
> advertisers to build a profile of you based on your search habits so
> they can serve more relevant content.
>
> Advertisers have very sophisticated targeting for their campaigns to
> make sure they are reaching the right potential buyers and use cookies
> to do this. Third party cookies have long been shrouded in controversy
> and are seen by many as an invasion of people’s privacy.

### Why are third party cookies problematic?

> Third party cookies enable brands and vendors to create user profiles
> based on their online behavior and activities. Unfortunately, third
> party cookies are often set by companies the user hasn’t even heard of
> or interacted with. Other than public perception and the years of
> misuse and abuse from advertisers, third party cookies are becoming
> increasingly inefficient and ineffective for advertisers to target
> users and track performance.
>
> Users are now spread across multiple connected devices and use them
> interchangeably. Third party cookies are unable to transfer across
> devices or even between apps meaning it is very hard to track the full
> buyer journey of a customer. This causes issues with correctly
> attributing conversions and budget to the right channels, ultimately
> causing wastage. With third party cookies, it also means users do not
> get a seamless experience with incorrect or out of date cookie data
> being fed to advertisers.
>
> Advertisers guided exclusively by third party cookies get an incorrect
> view of performance with users being counted multiple times and
> purchasers on one device being hounded by retargeting campaigns on
> another. In a privacy-oriented world, the online advertising industry
> must seek out a new alternative to third party cookies.

### What made Google decide to phase out third party cookies?

> The pro-privacy revolution we’re witnessing has deep effects on the
> online publishing and advertising industry. When it comes to online
> privacy and data security, Google has often been the leader of changes
> – especially in the era post [GDPR](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9028179?hl=en-AU) and [CCPA](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9614122?hl=en-AU). If you go back a bit and
> see the privacy changes Google introduced throughout the time, you’ll
> see that phasing out third party cookies was the next logical step.
>
> For instance, in 2019, Google announced they will be creating a Google
> Chrome [browser extension that offers more transparency](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ads-transparency-spotligh/gkbmnjmlhjnakmfjcejhlhpnibcbjdnl) to web users on
> how advertisers use their data to profile them better and serve
> specific ads. This empowered users to differentiate between first
> party cookies and second party cookies, as well as to switch off or
> delete cookies used for online ad targeting without having to
> sacrifice their first party cookies which can make browsing the
> internet much easier.  In addition, the tech giant [announced a new
> feature on Google Ads](https://blog.google/products/ads/transparency-choice-and-control-digital-advertising/) where users will now be able to see who has paid
> for an ad placement served to them along with any data segments used
> to personalize the ad such as location, time zone etc.
>
> The company decided to do so under the growing scepticism of tech
> giants and their use and storage of user data, particularly following
> [Facebook’s scandal with Cambridge Analytica](https://www.wired.com/story/cambridge-analytica-facebook-privacy-awakening/) where it was found they
> had shared the personal information of millions of its users with a
> political consulting firm connected to the campaigns of Donald Trump
> and Brexit. At the time, Google and Silicon Valley were dealing with
> increasing public and political pressure around privacy and their use
> of website user data with many of the tech giant’s [CEOs being called
> in front of Congress in the US](https://www.wired.com/story/congress-sundar-pichai-google-ceo-hearing/) to answer for their mistakes. Google
> got caught between two negatives here, which may be the reason why
> they pushed this privacy update (i.e. Google Chrome extension)
> forward. They wanted to take a stand, be transparent, and clearly
> communicate their commitment to privacy.

### What are website cookies and why do they matter?

> A website cookie is a small bit of data stored as a text file in a
> browser that allows websites to keep track of users and help them to
> customize the experience. Website cookies are used for core website
> functionalities like shopping carts, remembering login details and
> your preferred language and location etc.
>
> Here are a few examples of how website cookies work. When you log into
> a website, your user account is identified thanks to website cookies
> and the website receives a confirmation of your successful login. From
> that point on, you are identified as a logged in user. When you shop
> online, website cookies track your activity and ensure pleasant user
> experience for you.
>
> Without website cookies, your shopping cart would not store items
> you’ve selected to purchase when you move to some other page to
> continue browsing.  Website cookies have been the backbone of the
> internet since the early days of online browsing and shopping, helping
> to improve the user experience for site visitors, allowing websites to
> understand who their audience is, and making sure that advertisers
> deliver the most relevant messages possible.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, I don't use Chrome except for rare occasions when other browsers are failing, due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 2: Click the "Slashed eye" icon and alow those third party cookies on the website you are at the moment.
(I was inspired by Solution 1 by Stefano)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (unfortunately not a proper one):

1- Go to the notifications in your Disqus account. (https://disqus.com/home/notifications/)

2- Find someone to reply in it.

3- Drag or choose the image from your PC

4- After upload, cut&paste the link of the image to the which comment you want to reply.

I'm doing this whenever this problem started, also you don't need to change your browser settings & allow 3rd party cookies etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Enhanced tracking protection helps on firefox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lPA2.png)